# How to remove mycroft AI

Tags: uninstall, mycroft

I recently installed Mycroft AI on ubuntu 17.10 to try it out. But it seemed to slow down my PC. I want to remove it from my PC. How will I be able to do it? Thanks!

Edit:
I had installed it using instruction on [this](https://github.com/lolstring/gnome-shell-extension-mycroft/wiki/Installation) github page. I went back to the page and tried this from terminal -  `npm run uninstall-extension` to uninstall. But I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-16-generic  
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "uninstall-extension"  
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2  
npm ERR! path /home/ganesh/package.json  
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2  
npm ERR! syscall open  
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ganesh/package.json'  
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ganesh/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent   
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ganesh/npm-debug.log
```

Can you please help me make sense of it?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @Panther, please check in the edits of question!

Comment: Linking to that page does not tell me what you have done. Did you download the zip ? To where ? "Choose the directory Mycroft-core is installed" and your choice was ??? Why are you running npm ? Did you also install the Dev environment ? And the log "/home/ganesh/npm-debug.log" contains what information ? My guess is you can simply deactivate it in gnome-tweak tool and manually remove the location you installed . If you did not install the DEV environment there is nothing more to do. I am not positive as not all the scripts seem to be on that site.

Comment: You may also file a support request - https://github.com/lolstring/gnome-shell-extension-mycroft/issues